# How to do that an user has access to certain routes only when logged in?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, routes, jwt

I've done a login with google that works perfect. Which, when the login is completed, I return a jwt that I store in localStorage.

```
const data = {id_token};

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(({jwt}) => {

      if (jwt) {
        localStorage.setItem('x-token', jwt);
      }


  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
```

How do i do that the user has access to certain routes only when he got that token and that token be true? Because he could storage any data in the variable "x-token" on the localStorage in the navigator and, in that way, he could has access to any route.

On postman that validation of the jwt works properly and the users can access to certain routes only when they put the token in the "req.header". Now, how do i do the same but in the navigator?

```
const validateJwt = (req, res, next) => {

let token = req.header('x-token')

//If the header is not empty, then validate the header and the token.
if (!token) {
    res.status(400).json({
        msg: 'Token doesn´t exists'
    })

}else{

    jsonwebtoken.verify(token, process.env.SECRETORPRIVATEKEY, (err, decoded) => {

        if (err) {
            res.status(403).json({
                msg: 'Token no valid'
            })

        }else{
            next();
        }

    });    
     
}}
```

Comment: app.use('/protected',validateJwt(req,res,next), function (req,res,next){  //this function will be called only jwt verification is passed. });

Comment: yes but how do i set a header to receive in req.header?

Comment: Set this in your fetch option parameter ```headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <JWT token>"
  }```

Comment: On server ```let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). If you want one function to be run after control reaches one of your paths with a specific method but before your main path handler function you can use middlewares. They are good for logging, validations, parsing etc.
You already have your validateJwt function, just put it after your route:

```
app.use('/auth',
validateJwt(req,res,next),
 (req,res,next) =>{ 

});
```

Comment: Yes, i did that. But how do i call the req.header from the navigator???

Comment: What is meant by the navigator? Anyway, is req.header(HEADERNAME) or req.headers() not working?

Comment: Yes, how do i send a req.header? Where is it located?

Comment: You can use this while sending your request [Headers.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/set)

Comment: It didnt work. I want to set a header with the JWT, and then receive it with the req.header to pass the middleware. In postman there´s a section to set a header with any name. I want to do the same but in the navigator.